# Go's SSH client and PTY on AIX

Tags: go, ssh, aix, pty

I doubt that I'll get an answer here as AIX is very rare thing but I should try at least.

**The background**

We have the program. The program uses `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` library to connect to the remote services and do some things. The program is part of the large service and widely tested by end-users. It works without issues (at least related to connection) not only with all Linux-based clients (include quite old things like Ubuntu 12.02) but also with the clients on FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, MacOSX, Solaris SPARC, HP-UX and other *nixes. So looks like it wasn't tested only on the Samsung refrigerators. And yesterday I was sure that it will be able to connect to the refrigerator and do what is needed without any issues. But that was yesterday...

**The problem**

Today we decided to add AIX support to our program. And we partly failed.

The problem description is simple: after `pty` request program stops working. I mean I can do `ssh.RequestPty` it executes without any issues but when I'm trying to execute commands after the app just hangs. Without errors, without nothing. Just hangs.

*When it works?*

1. It works in PuTTY/KiTTY so I'm able to connect to the remote host.
2. If I remove `requestPty` - everything works. But we need `pty` for the `sudo`.
3. It works without issues if I request `session.Shell` even with `pty` requested. So if I write kind of interactive shell, it works perfectly.

**What have I tried so far**

I tried to debug so far as I could. The last command that executes is `ch.sendMessage(msg)` from `ssh/channel.go`. I mean it writes packet and that's all. No data returned from the remote host.

For the tests, I used 3 versions of AIX - 5.3, 6.1 and 7.1. No difference.

OpenSSH versions are different:

- 5.3 - OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
- 6.1 & 7.1 - OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

All machines are running in LPARs but I doubt this is related to the issue.

I have no idea what is wrong. And I even can't say if this is common AIX issue or only our test machine. Here is the sample program that should write `IT WORKS` if it works

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    server := "127.0.0.1:22"
    user := "root"
    p := "password"

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: user,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(p)},
    }
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", server, config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Comment below and everything works
    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400,
    }

    if err := session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // Comment above and everything works
    session.Run("echo 1")
    println("IT WORKS")
}
```

If you have AIX somewhere around and can run this code against it I'd appreciate your feedback.

If you have any ideas (even crazy) why it may fail and where else I can look, don't be shy.

**Update (2017-03-02):**

By suggestion from @LorinczyZsigmond I launched `sshd` in debug mode. Results are a bit strange.

Here is part of `Debian 9.0 OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016` log after sample program execution:

```
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request exec reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req exec

debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY

debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10

debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.

debug2: channel 0: rfd 10 isatty
debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK

debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
```

It works as expected.

Now the same block from `AIX 7.1 OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013` log:

```
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/42
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request exec reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req exec
debug1: Values: options.num_allow_users: 0
debug1: RLOGIN VALUE  :1
debug1: audit run command euid 0 user root command 'whoami'

setsid: Operation not permitted.
```

After `setsid: Operation not permitted.` it does nothing until I kill it with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. When I kill it it returns:

```
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: channel 0: rfd 10 isatty
debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug2: notify_done: reading
Exiting on signal 2
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: session_pty_cleanup: session 0 release /dev/pts/42
debug1: audit session close euid 0 user root tty name /dev/pts/42
debug1: audit event euid 0 user root event 12 (SSH_connabndn)
debug1: Return Val-1 for auditproc:0
```

And sends the result of `whoami` back to the client. This looks like a bug in SSH server, but is this possible for the 2 different versions?

Another interesting fact is when I run `sshd` with `truss` (kind of `strace` for AIX) the output looks like this:

```
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/42
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request exec reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req exec
debug1: Values: options.num_allow_users: 0
debug1: RLOGIN VALUE  :1
debug1: audit run command euid 0 user root command 'whoami'

debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY

debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10

debug2: channel 0: rfd 10 isatty
debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK

setsid: Operation not permitted.

debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
```

But `truss` output is a bit more strange than `strace` one (at least for someone who don't use *nix trace tools on daily basis) so I don't understand what is going on in the logs. If there is someone more skilled with this stuff here is the part of the trace data http://pastebin.com/YdzQwbt2 from `debug1: RLOGIN VALUE  :1`.

Also, in the logs, I found that `ssh.Shell()` works because it doesn't request `pty`. It starts an interactive session (or something like that). But in my case, the interactive session is not an option.

Comment: There are support forums for AIX on IBM websites. (Sorry I don't have the URLS anymore (and they have likely changed anyway)). Also, there is pretty good group of AIX users on http://ittoolbox.com forums. You do a simple sign up, and then search/browse their forums. Once you find the AIX forum, you may need to "join" it separately. I don't think you'll find the exact answer there, but a better place to get AIX help. Good luck.

Comment: Uh. Why xterm? Isn't it the program supposed to run remotely? If yes, does it have a chance to do that successfully (that is, sees a proper DISPLAY variable in its environment block etc)? What if you try something else instead?

Comment: Random questions: Why would you use `sudo` if you connect as `root`? Why don't you upgrade to OpenSSL-1.0.2k and OpenSSH-7.4p1? Did try to run sshd in debug mode (`sshd -D -d -d -d p anotherport`)?

Comment: @shellter thank you. I'll try.

Comment: @kostix thank you for your question. Maybe I explained improperly. The program connects to the remote server via SSH then gathers some data and sends it back to the main service. Also, we have the local agent which is recommended way to work with our service but AIX is not supported by Go so the only way to gather data is to use the program from the question.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond thank you for your reply. We don't require to use root account from end-users. They may log in as root, as a user with sudo privileges, and as a simple user. You are right and in first and last cases we don't need `pty`, but some part of our users uses the second variant so we should support it too. And thank you for the idea about debugging from the server side. I'll try.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my comment: I was on mobile and had no simple way to see the docs so I thought `RequestPty()` also starts a remote process. Now I see that's the terminal name string.

Comment: Hm. I wonder whether specifying `vt100` or even `dumb` fixes the problem.

Comment: @kostix I already tried `vt100` yesterday. Tried `dumb` right now with the same result. A bit later I'll try ssh debug as @LorinczyZsigmond suggested but not sure if it will display `pty` related issues.

Comment: You can also connect with the openssh client with `-vvv` to see how that might be handling the connection differently.

Comment: @JimB @kostix I compared Debian and AIX `sshd` debug output and updated the post. It seems like a bug in OpenSSH but I don't know if this is possible for two different versions of OpenSSH. Anyway, I'm pretty sure now that this is not Go SSH implementation issue. So I'll just try to replace commands that require `sudo` with alternatives when it is possible.

Comment: From the setsid() man page: EPERM  The calling process is already a process group leader, or the process group ID of a process other than the calling process matches the process ID of the calling process. -- but why sshd would be hitting that is beyond me.  And why this is specific to your particular path is also very odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

better late than never

IBM said it was a bug in openssh - race condition while PTY allocation
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IV82042

fixed in package openssh.base.server:7.5.102.1500

it strange that bug only occurs in aix, never in linux. nevertheless, problem is solved in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with "Allocating pty" and then exiting from ssh session. Here is log of my sshd debug:

sshd drops connection with error :3004-010 Failed setting terminal ownership and mode.

> **debug1: Allocating pty.**
>   debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/2
>   **debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 13 (0xd)
>
>   debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 18 (0x12)**
>   debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
>   debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
>   debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
>   debug2: Ignoring env request LANG: disallowed name
>   debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
>   debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
>   debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
>   debug1: Values: options.num_allow_users: 0
>   debug1: RLOGIN VALUE  :1
>
> setsid: Operation not permitted.
>
> The OS is AIX 7.1 (7100-04-03-1642)

The goal of my environment is to authenticate user on AIX through remote ldap user over ssh (ldap server actually is novell eDirectory). 
So, I had similar issue with user authentication.

I fixed login over ssh as in eDirectory Schema (rfc2703), added following object extensions to the user:

posixAccount
posixGroup
shadowAccount
uamPosixUser (as I am not sure is it necessary this object)

I just want to note that on OS AIX following user isn't local, not exist in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

V.Davidov

Comment: Thanks. I'll try.